# How to parse mutiple fastq files from a directory?

Tags: python, file, sequence, biopython, fasta

I am trying to create a loop to parse one by one 5 fasta files that I have in a same directory. Now I will explain a little bit, I have 5 fasta files with the genome of 5 microorganism, each one in each file. The idea is to obtain de Ids from each file and put them in to a dictionary `{Mo_Id1:0, Mo_Id2:0...,Mo_Id5:0}`

I think my loop reads the first file, but then it gave me the following error; `No such file or directory 'GCF_000006532.1_ASM696v3_genomic.fna'` (this is the name of the second file that I have in my folder).
I show you my code:

```py
from Bio import SeqIO
import os
dicc_MO=[]
    
files = os.listdir("/home/alumno/Escritorio/Asig2Python/Semana4/Tarea/genomas/genomas")

for f in files:
    for record_seqMO in SeqIO.parse(f,"fasta"):
        record_seqMO.id not in dicc_MO: 
            dicc_MO[record_seqMO.id] = 0
        
print(dicc_MO)
```

With dicc_MO i was trying to check if the loop was OKEY, in that case, I should have a dictionary where the keys are the microorganism name and the values are 0.

Answer (score -1):

The command `os.listdir` only shows the name of files without path. So you need to add path to each file name in your list `files`.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import os
dicc_MO=[]
    
files=os.listdir("/home/alumno/Escritorio/Asig2Python/Semana4/Tarea/genomas/genomas")

for f in files:
    f = f + "/home/alumno/Escritorio/Asig2Python/Semana4/Tarea/genomas/genomas/"
    for record_seqMO in SeqIO.parse(f,"fasta"):
    ...
```